# Use Selenium to click all youtube comment 'reply' buttons and get channel links

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, youtube, selenium-chromedriver

Goal is to scrape all **youtube channel links** from the youtube video comment section. The current code just gets the usernames and not the channel links and doesn't look at the user inside replies. I don't get how to do this and why my xPaths are wrong.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_p2NvO6KrBs')
time.sleep(5)

#Scrolling
for i in range(4):
    #scroll 1000 px
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,(window.pageYOffset+1000))')
    #waiting for the page to load
    time.sleep(1.5) 


#replies
replies = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="more-replies"]')
time.sleep(1)
replies.click()


comment_div=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contents"]')
comments=comment_div.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="author-text"]')
for comment in comments:
    print(comment.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the href attribute if you want the channel url:

```
for comment in comments:
    print(comment.get_attribute('href'))
```

If you want the channels of each reply (of each comment) too then you can try the following. I've added comments on some lines for context...

```
main_comments = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#contents #comment') # get all the comments

for mc in main_comments:
    main_comment_channel = mc.find_element_by_id('author-text').get_attribute('href')
    print('The commenters channel is: ' + main_comment_channel) # print the channel of the main comment

    replies = mc.find_element_by_xpath('..//*[@id="replies"]') # get the replies section of the above comment
    if replies.text.startswith('View'): # check if there are any replies
        replies.find_element_by_css_selector('a').click() # if so open the replies
        time.sleep(3) # wait for load (better strategy should be used here

        for reply in replies.find_elements_by_id('author-text'):
            reply_channel = reply.get_attribute('href')
            print('Reply channel: ' + reply_channel) # print the channel of each reply
```

Full solution including writing to .txt file

```
file = open("output.txt","w+")

driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_p2NvO6KrBs')
time.sleep(5)

#new scrolling
while(len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#sections>#continuations #spinner')) > 0):
    #scroll 1000 px
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,(window.pageYOffset+1000))')
    #waiting for the page to load
    time.sleep(1.5) 


main_comments = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#contents #comment') # get all the comments

for mc in main_comments:
    main_comment_channel = mc.find_element_by_id('author-text').get_attribute('href')
    file.write('The commenters channel is: ' + main_comment_channel + '\n') #write the channel of the main comment to file

    replies = mc.find_element_by_xpath('..//*[@id="replies"]') # get the replies section of the above comment
    if replies.text.startswith('View'): # check if there are any replies
        reply = replies.find_element_by_css_selector('a');
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", reply) # bring view replies into view
        driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,(window.pageYOffset-150))') # cater for the youtube header
        reply.click() # if so open the replies
        time.sleep(3) # wait for load (better strategy should be used here

        for reply in replies.find_elements_by_id('author-text'):
            reply_channel = reply.get_attribute('href')
            file.write('Reply channel: ' + reply_channel + '\n') # write the channel of each reply to file

file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you help me printing the results into a .txt file

Comment: I've added a full solution (without driver creation). But this adds the file you wanted, but also I noticed that the original scrolling may not have loaded all comments, so this does that. Also we need to bring the 'view replies' button into view before clicking but also cater for the youtube header which could hide it. One thing I haven't catered for is sometimes youtube shows a feedback popup (and some other one) but didn't load all the time for me - you should be able to cater for this fairly easily though.

Comment: Can you help me with another problem that seems to appear? :) (Thread)

Comment: It's best to create a separate question for this, just a hint though - look at at where you are opening the file and closing it (for loop is catching you out on the close).

Comment: Ah yes my bad. whatever got it fixed. Really appreciate your help.