# Use Selenium to click all youtube comment 'reply' buttons and get the username and content of the replies and comments

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, youtube, selenium-chromedriver

My goal is to scrape all the youtube comments and replies along with the username from a youtube comment section.

What I have done so far only gets the comments and not the user inside replies. It is relatively similar with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61978462/use-selenium-to-click-all-youtube-comment-reply-buttons-and-get-channel-links) but the Youtube interface has changed.

Below is a snippet of my code where it would input into Sqlite the authors and the comments or replies.

```
REPLIES_word = None

    replies = mc.find_element(By.XPATH, '..//*[@id="replies"]') # get the replies section of the above comment

    REPLIES_word = replies.text.split(" ")[1]
    if (REPLIES_word == "replies"): # check if there are any replies
        reply = replies.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a')
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", reply) # bring view replies into view
        driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,(window.pageYOffset-150))') # cater for the youtube header
        try:
            reply.click() # if so open the replies
        except:
            pass
        time.sleep(sleep_timer) # wait for load (better strategy should be used here

        try: 
            more_replies = replies.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="button"]/ytd-button-renderer')
            if more_replies.text.startswith('Show'):
                more_reply = more_replies.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a');
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", more_reply) # bring view replies into view
                driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,(window.pageYOffset-150))') # cater for the youtube header
                more_reply.click() # if so open the replies
                time.sleep(sleep_timer) # wait for load (better strategy should be used here
        except:
            pass


        print ("Reply: ")

        reply_counter = 0

        for reply in replies.find_elements(By.ID, 'author-text'):
            reply_name = reply.text
            reply_counter = reply_counter + 1
            print(str(reply_counter) + " : " + reply_name)
            insert_reply_author( cursor, comment_counter, reply_counter, reply_name)

        print()

        reply_counter = 0

        for reply in replies.find_elements(By.ID, 'content-text'):
            reply_content = reply.text
            reply_counter = reply_counter + 1
            print(str(reply_counter) + " : " + reply_content)
            insert_reply_comment( connection, cursor, comment_counter, reply_counter, reply_content )

        print("----------")
```

I'm currently having trouble with the line:

reply = replies.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a')

since Youtube interface has changed and I don't know how Selenium would be able to click the nested "Replies" section.

Any help would be appreciated.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/youtube_comments_replies_scraper2.py", line 156, in \<module\>
get_usernames_comments_replies( connection, cursor, driver )
File "/youtube_comments_replies_scraper2.py", line 70, in get_usernames_comments_replies
reply = replies.find_element(By.NAME, 'replies')
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 433, in find_element
return self.\_execute(Command.FIND_CHILD_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})\["value"\]
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 410, in \_execute
return self.\_parent.execute(command, params)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"\[name="replies"\]"}
```

Comment: Why not just using [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Comments: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list) and [CommentThreads: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list), as discussed in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71261586)?

Comment: @BenjaminLoison I've actually tried before using it and not all comments and replies are showing. That's why I resulted in using Selenium to scrape manually. I'm in the middle of reviewing the Youtube Data API v3 and even if I'm not sure of this statement and just checked other codes, not all the replies and comments returns especially on the videos with thousands of comments.

Comment: Could you provide a video id that doesn't return *all the replies and comments* and please also share a comment id (like [`UgzuC3zzpRZkjc5Qzsd4AaABAg`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNQXAC9IVRw&lc=UgzuC3zzpRZkjc5Qzsd4AaABAg)) that doesn't appear in YouTube Data API v3 while it appears on YouTube UI?

Comment: Your code and error message don't match up - the error message says it's for `reply = replies.find_element(By.NAME, 'replies')` but there's no such line in your code snippet and your error mentions nothing about `By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a'`....